# How to disable reduce to icon button and enlarge button to a windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

what is the method for to disable reduce to icon button and enlarge button to a windows form.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You can't disable them afaik, only hide them.

Answer (score 4):

Your form should have the following properties: `MinimizeBox` and `MaximizeBox`.  Setting them to `false` will remove those buttons.

Answer (score 4):

Set the form properties MinimizeBox and MaximizeBox to false.

Answer (score 2):

In the propieties of the form:

[image]

Set them to false.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

In the properties panel

OR

Add these lines in your Form:

```
MaximizeBox = false;
MinimizeBox = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your forms constructor right after the `InitializeComponents()` method, or `_OnLoad` event

```
this.MaximizeBox = false;
this.MinimizeBox = false;
```

Or simply change the properties of MaximizeBox and MinimizeBox properties to False from the Designer properties window.